APK not found/ APK doesn't exist - System App on Anbox Cloud Appliance
I'm trying to install an app as system app in anbox cloud appliance however it keeps giving me this error: "APK not found..." or it says "APK doesn't exist" with the given address. even though I tried every type of addressing whether correct or even incorrect ones.
I installed system app couple of times and when I named pre-start.sh hook file it worked, but now it keeps me giving me this error. The strange thing is previous times, for each system app, different type of addressing was used and it worked; but the common thing they had was the name of pre-start file which was: pre-start.sh.
The suggested addressing from the documentation was --apk="${ADDON_DIR}/app.apk which I tried and I also edited in many ways but it doesn't work.
This is the directory structure:
├── app.apk

├── hooks
│   └── pre-start

└── manifest.yaml

These are the commands in the pre-start file:
if  [ "$INSTANCE_TYPE" = "regular" ]; then
  
exit 0

fi

aam install-system-app \
  --package-name=com.canonical.anbox.out_of_band_v2 \
  --apk=/home/faraz/mine/app.apk

For my last attempts, I renamed the pre-start to pre-start.sh and tried different ways of addressing the APK, however right now it doesn't work.
keep in mind that I get the error for the application not created in the dashboard of Anbox cloud appliance, and it has a log section from which I see the error messages from there; the error is this:
Jul 26 10:25:13 ams-cqhnisc921260635dot0 anbox-starter[1142]: ERROR: apk file /home/faraz/mine/app.apk d

